# What does the phrase ''but rather'' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, phrase-usage

In this following context, what does the phrase ''but rather'' mean? Is it ''whowever'' or ''in fact''?

Should I take as: Hence the body is not a persisting something, but the body is rather a continually changing process of arising ...?

Please, simplify to me this sentence...

Thanks to All...

The context:

> Hence the body is not a persisting something, but rather a continually
> changing process of arising and passing away, consisting of a
> perpetual dying out and arising anew of cells.

Source:
Page.6
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to simplify it, then replace "but rather" with "it is"

This is a common construct, if a little flowery.

The author basically means "instead" - the other key words in there are "is not a", if that helps?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mike Brockington...

Answer (score 0):

It means something like *or/but is better described as*: it supplements or replaces a less specific or appropriate description with a more specific or appropriate one.

In the passage you quoted it is explicitly giving a better description as opposed to a less good one  ("**not** a persistent something").

So it's closer to "however" (which is what I think you meant) than "in fact", and your paraphrase is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Comment: Definitely not an "or" situation , rather it is an "opposite of" situation.

Comment: You're right, @MikeBrockington, in this use it's a "but" rather than an "or", so I've added that as an alternative.